# undefined method `includes' for object instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2 to build an app. At one of my views, I got the following message:

> N+1 Query detected
>     Politician => [:account]
>     Add to your finder: :includes => [:account]
>
> N+1 Query method call stack
>
> app/models/user.rb:19:in `account'
>
> app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `index'

Here is my action at home controller:

```
@account = current_user.account
@new_contacts = current_user.contacts.created_this_week.count
@new_collabs = current_user.collaborators.created_this_week.count
```

And the relevant section of user model:

```
belongs_to :role, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
delegate :account, to: :role
delegate :collaborators, to: :role
delegate :contacts, to: :role
```

I already tried to the following:

```
@account = current_user.account.includes(:contacts, :collaborators)
```

But I only get the error:

```
undefined method `includes' for <Account:0x007fa7474e04a8>
```

I did some research and what it seems is that includes works only for relations (which is not the case).

Is bullet worrying for nothing? What can I do to this stop being a N+1 query?

Thanks!

Comment: what is in line#19 ? show plz

Comment: @R_O_R line 19 is

`delegate :account, to: :role`
line 6 of home_controller is:

  `@account = current_user.account`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`includes` can only be called on `ActiveRecord::Relation`s or `ActiveRecord::Base` children classes, `account` seems to be a instace of a model, thus not respond to `ActiveRecord::Relation` methods like `includes`. It seems a false positive from `bullet` as soon as you are only getting account from `current_user`, although I don't recommend delagations to associations, it can lead to N + 1 problems in the feature.

---

Replacing delagate with AR association:

Assuming that `Account` is a regular `ActiveRecord` model you can use `has_one` macro (look at [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) for more details):

```
has_one :account, through: :role
```

It's very handful when you need to iterate through users:

```
# You can avoid `N + 1`
User.includes(:account).limit(50).each { |u| puts u.name }
```

Comment: So what to you reccomend to avoid the delegations in this case?

Comment: Assuming that `Account` is a regular `ActiveRecord` model you can use `has_one` macro (look at [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) for more details):  `has_one :account, through: :role`

Comment: role is actually a polymorphic association, so when I do 
`has_one :account, through: :role` I get the following error: `Cannot have a has_one :through association 'User#account' which goes through the polymorphic association 'User#role'.`

Maybe I should stick with delegate?